# why LinkedList does not implements RandomAccess Interface to make the retrieval of elements faster?

Tags: java, list, collections

Why only ArrayList and Vector implements RandomAccess interface and LinkedList doesn't? As I understand it, the RandomAccess implemented class can make the retrieval of elements faster in collection.

Also, if I try to make a custom class which extends java.util.LinkedList and also implements RandomAccess interface, does that make the custom class just like LinkedList but with RandomAccess?

Here is code which is implementing what I stated in the second point:

```java
public class ExtendedLinkedList extends java.util.LinkedList implements java.util.RandomAccess {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        ExtendedLinkedList ell = new ExtendedLinkedList();
        
        System.out.println(ell instanceof java.util.RandomAccess); // True
        System.out.println(ell instanceof java.util.LinkedList); // True
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Also, forget about the existence of `LinkedList`, 99% of the time, it performs worse than `ArrayList` (even for most cases where people claim linked lists are faster).

Comment: Letting `LinkedList` implement `RandomAccess` would contradict the purpose of this interface completely. And Mark Rotteveel is right, just don’t use `LinkedList`. There’s this [famous tweet](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248) from the author…

Answer (score 4):

Implementing [the `RandomAccess` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/RandomAccess.html) does not make random access faster.

Indeed, it doesn't do *anything at all*, really.

It only exists as a marker interface: it's used to *mark* list implementations that *already provide efficient random indexed access*.

In other words: `ArrayList` and `Vector` implement `RandomAccess` **because** they provide efficient random access. `LinkedList` does *not* implement it, because it does *not* provide efficient random access (accessing a specific index from the `List` interface requires potentially iterating up to half of the list).

If you extend `LinkedList` then you *should not* implement `RandomAccess` unless you also change the implementation of `get(int)` to be efficient (at which point I'd say you probably shouldn't be extending `LinkedList` at all).